# How to show sequence of visits to nodes in a tree

Tags: diagram

I am working on my thesis and I am wondering is there a better way to describe a sequence of visits:

1. from S there is a visit to node A
2. from S there is a visit to node B
3. from S there is a visit to node A again

This is my attempt to describe the sequence and I asked a few people if its clear and they all said no.

[image]

Comment: I have a CS background. Based solely on the visual my first thought was that the left most path was traversed background 1 time, the second traversed 3 times, and the third traversed 2 times. After reading your description the diagram does make sense, though I'm not sure why you would have a visual for this information. Can you give us any more context like what these represent? That might help us provide alternative suggestions

Comment: I thought adding the sequence diagram would help the reader instantly see what's going on. Maybe have a description by itself was enough.

Comment: If the sequence always alternates A -> B -> A -> B, I would just say that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want things to appear more *sequential*, perhaps...

[image]

Or similar.

Comment: I don't know if it would actually make it better or worse, but it might also make sense to put small circles/dots at the start of each branching line to possibly help with the "readability". And I mean especially if this was any more complex, that could be a good way to perhaps start color coding the branches: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h516.png)